# Failing to host two web servers with nginx (host linode, ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: nginx, webserver, linode

I've set up nginx to run as in the following :

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name MYWEBSITE;
.....
}

server{
     listen 8000;
     server_name MYWEBSITE;
.....
}
```

Whenever I go to MYWEBSITE, on port 80 the page opens but on my port 8000 it's failing.
What I have tried is reversing server's  port so I made sure that both of my web servers are working.
Also I have tried the same setup on a local machine and it's working.
This setup is for my linode server. So I guess it's something related to linode.

Ports are open and this was checked using Nmap. 
Where do I need to look for solving the issue ? Any thoughts?

Comment: Using another domain name did the trick. But i would like to know how it can be done with same domain name but on different port.

Comment: The config should work. Are you sure that it's allowing connections on 8000 for incoming connections?

Comment: How can i check this? Maybe i missed something here.